# What is the opposite of gem-like?

Tags: antonyms

Does anyone know what would be an appropriate antonym for *gem-like*?

That is, a word for something that is not valuable, not beautiful, brilliant, or clear, and may be soft, where a gem is hard.

*Edit:*  We can say *gem-like* to mean someone with attractive qualities.  I was looking for an opposite along that line.

Comment: Erm, I think your problem is that "jewel" doesn't have an opposite, unless you count "paste".  Can you give some sense of what quality of jewels you're trying to evoke the opposite of?

Comment: People, people, people: not all words have antonyms. It's a fact of English and a fact of life.

Comment: It depends on context, I suppose.  Jewels have a number of distinctive characteristics: hardness, clarity, brilliance, intrinsic value...  Change any one of them, and you have the opposite.  In chemistry, the flame of a burning gas can be described as "gem-like"; in fact, the phrase is used to describe ignited flatulence.  So perhaps the opposite of "jewel-like" is "like an unlit fart"?

Comment: As MT_Head points out, without further context this question is impossible to answer. Opposites are *defined* by context. *Man* can be the opposite of *woman*, or the opposite of *boy*, or the opposite of *animal* — even though a man *is* an animal (and not a plant). So, please provide further context, then this question can be reopened. Otherwise the most helpful answer we can offer is *jewel-unlike*, which is not really helpful at all.

Comment: @I edited the question by changing "jewel" to "gem." I believe that the new question can be answered (as it was before closing), and nominate it for reopening

Comment: I'm going to suggest "banal" as an answer to this question.  A banal person would be someone who generally makes one feel worse for time in their company.

Comment: @Christi: we are not assuming they are not questions. We are working on improving them. *This is how the SE engine is supposed to work.* If a question is unclear, it gets closed as such. If it's improved, it gets reopened. If it isn't, it stays closed because an unclear question doesn't help anyone, least of all the OP himself.

Comment: @RegDwightΒВBẞ8 Fair enough, although the fact that that needed explaining suggests that the "closed" terminology may not be helpful - particularly as it makes no suggestion that improving the question then flagging is a way to get it re-opened.  It seems that one certainly needs more rep than I have to do anything other than flag the question for a mod's attention if it has been improved.  This is a technique which has had mixed success in the past (not necessarily on this particular SE site.  Some mods can get quite defensive about their closes.)

Comment: When you say you want the opposite of "someone with attractive qualities", should that mean "someone with a *lack* of attractive qualities", or "someone with UNattractive (ugly, repellent, repulsive,...) qualities"? Because those two could be very different.

Comment: @ FrustratedWithFormsDesigner, I guess, in general, opposite would mean having the opposite qualities and not just "not having the qualities".

Comment: Do you want some kind of opposite of the physical object of a jewel or gem, or do you rather want, for a concept that is -metaphorically represented by a gem, the oposite of that concept? How close literal do you want to be? Also what is the context. Is it 'That person is a real gem'? (and you want to replace 'gem' to give the opposite impression) 'That person is a real loser', 'that person went over like a lead balloon', 'that person is as charismatic as a bucket of snot'. What are your criteria?

Comment: @RegDwightΒВBẞ8 See what I mean?

Comment: Sigh, not one of FumbleFingers, Matt Эллен, aedia λ, Jasper Loy or Mahnax even attempted to improve the question, suggest an improvement via a comment or ask for clarification from the questioner. It's so much easier to just click on the vote to close link than spend any effort actually trying to help make the question better.

Comment: @MarkBooth Why would they?  As the coloured box says, it's not a good fit to the Q&A format.  Irredeemably so, in my opinion; I don't think there's any change that any of these people could have made, that would have made the question acceptable.

Comment: @MarkBooth What would you suggest? You can improve it yourself too. Personally, I didn't vote to close but the criteria of "not having the qualities" of a gem could equally be "panda" or "purple"

Comment: @simchona - Why should ***I*** need to improve it, I think the improvements which led to it being re-opened were fine. In this case I feel that your logical fallacy is ***[tu quoque](http://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/tu-quoque)***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to suggest "banal" as an answer to this question. A banal person would be someone who generally makes one feel worse for time in their company.  If you're looking for a word which specifically conveys lack of value, "worthless" is also a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

*[Rough](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rough)-like* or just plain *rough*.

> a : something in a crude, unfinished, or preliminary state

See also:  a diamond in the rough.

**EDIT:**  After reading OP's edits I thought to look up *[boorish](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boorish)*.  While that doesn't seem to fit exactly, I thought this synonym discussion on the page was interesting:

> boorish, churlish, loutish, clownish mean uncouth in manners or
>   appearance.
>
> **[boorish](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boorish)** implies rudeness of manner due to insensitiveness
>   to others' feelings and unwillingness to be agreeable .
>
> **[churlish](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/churlish)** suggests surliness, unresponsiveness, and
>   ungraciousness .
>
> **[loutish](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loutish)** implies bodily awkwardness
>   together with stupidity .
>
> **[clownish](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clownish)** suggests ill-bred
>   awkwardness, ignorance or stupidity, ungainliness, and often a
>   propensity for absurd antics .

Comment: I would simply use *rough* – he is a rough character. *Course* is another good one.

Comment: I would too upon OP's edits.

Comment: @zpletan: Did you mean *coarse*?

Comment: @JohnY, yes, I did mean *coarse*. Thanks for catching.

Answer (score 0):

I've not heard *gem-like* used of people, but I assume OP means something akin to [she's](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%27s%20a%20gem%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22she%27s%20a%20gem%22&oq=%22she%27s%20a%20gem%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.3...7186.7186.2.7775.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0..1.0.5w4cSIf5vnY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2f7879b441b121c8&biw=1237&bih=902)/[he's a gem](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%27s%20a%20gem%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%27s%20a%20gem%22&oq=%22he%27s%20a%20gem%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.3...59754.59754.3.60521.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0..1.0.epdqIdN3cE0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2f7879b441b121c8&biw=1237&bih=902), which are both common enough. The sense there is that she/he is a *valuable* person - well worth knowing because they have fine personality traits (not because they have *wealth*). The "antonym" would thus be someone who *isn't* worth knowing...

> [He's a nobody](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%27s%20a%20gem%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%27s%20a%20nobody%22&oq=%22he%27s%20a%20nobody%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.3...502734.508317.6.508828.20.20.0.0.0.0.144.2149.9j11.20.0.K5nIJKEUz-Q&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2f7879b441b121c8&biw=1237&bih=902)/[nothing](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%27s%20a%20gem%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%27s%20a%20nothing%22&oq=%22he%27s%20a%20nothing%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.3...71736.74071.9.74325.9.5.4.0.0.0.140.510.3j2.9.0.mIagVdjS8yQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2f7879b441b121c8&biw=1237&bih=902).
>
> [He's a waste of time](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%27s%20a%20gem%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%27s%20a%20waste%20of%20time%22&oq=%22he%27s%20a%20waste%20of%20time%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.3...61652.65907.10.66339.20.20.0.0.0.0.149.2190.7j13.20.0.FedBQdgXOv4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2f7879b441b121c8&biw=1237&bih=902) (or my personal favourite, [...a waste of **space**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%27s%20a%20gem%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%27s%20a%20waste%20of%20space%22&oq=%22he%27s%20a%20waste%20of%20space%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.12...77115.79177.11.81777.8.4.4.0.0.0.131.471.1j3.8.0.QZmmHLlztjw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2f7879b441b121c8&biw=1237&bih=902)).

Comment: My favorite is "a waste of carbon", which can be interpreted in several ways; in this context, it could mean "instead of being wasted on your useless carcass, that carbon could have been used to make a diamond!"

Comment: When hammered open, the small chest proved to contain sparkling gems, dispersed, almost hidden, among numerous dull greyish chunks of dross.

Answer (score 0):

In the sense that a gem is one who is held in high esteem, regard, or affection, then some antonyms may be: unappealing, unlikable (or disliked), unattractive.